# Screenshot for SVG based UI Angular 6

Tags: angular, svg

We have to add a feature in the application (Angular 6 + Bootstrap) that has SVG in it , I tried using html2canvas but SVG's are not coming as part of screenshot.

```
 html2canvas(this.screen.nativeElement).then( canvasres => {
  this.canvas1.nativeElement.src = canvasres.toDataURL();
  this.downloadLink.nativeElement.href = canvasres.toDataURL('image/png');
  this.downloadLink.nativeElement.download = 'screenshot.png';
  this.downloadLink.nativeElement.click();
 });
});
```

Can you please suggest how can we achieve taking screenshot for this UI?

Comment: Adding SVGs to canvases taint them : they can not be saved anymore. I think the same happens to canvases added to canvases. If you want to resolve that, you should instead draw on a canvas directly, or simply make the image downloadable.

Comment: We resolved the issue by using navigator.mediadevices option , it takes full screen screenshot but it works.